# Too few arguments to function Path:Controllers\AdminController::confirmStatement(), 1 passed in Paht:Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите в чем ошибка?

Вот мой AdminController

```
public function confirmStatement($id,$user_id){

    $user_status = User::find($user_id);

    $confirmStat = Orders::find(id);

    $user_status->orders = 1;

    $confirmStat->status_moderate = 0;

    $confirmStat->order_status = 1;


    $user_status->save();

    $confirmStat->save();
  }
```

Web.php

```
Route::get('/admin/confirm/{id}/','AdminController@confirmStatement')
     ->name('confirmStatement');
```

И мой blade

```
<a href="{{route('confirmStatement', $el->id, $el->user_id)}}">
```

Я получал id с таблицы orders но не могу оттуда же взять user_id,подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема?

Comment: `route('confirmStatement', ['id' => $el->id, 'user_id' => $el->user_id])`

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте user_id в роут web.php

Было

```
Route::get('/admin/confirm/{id}/','AdminController@confirmStatement')
 ->name('confirmStatement');
```

Стало

```
Route::get('/admin/confirm/{id}/{user_id}','AdminController@confirmStatement')
 ->name('confirmStatement');
```